# Reminder Numbers pattern/relationship finding Algorithm

Tags: numbers, pattern-matching, equation, reminders

I need a little help regarding this small problem. Given two number a and b and two reminders rem1 and rem2. You need to find all number x which is satisfying following condition.

**x%a = rem1 and x%b = rem2**

e.g. a=11, b=14, rem1=0, rem2=2 then ans is x=44

I know one simple solution is via for loop but that is not good approach. Actually I need a formula or some pattern which will give me answer efficiently.